# Sending modem AT command and parsing result

Tags: linux, bash, shell, at-command, modem

I would like to send `AT` command to my modem by using shell script and parse the result in order to verify if the OK is returned.

```
at=`echo -ne "AT+CFUN1=1\r\n" > /dev/ttyUSB0 | cat /dev/ttyUSB0`
```

What is the best way to parse the at1 variable and extract "OK" or "ERROR" otherwise ?

Comment: You cannot send AT command from the normal command line to a modem. You need to use something like `socat` or `minicom` to establish a serial connection with the modem. See: [**How to send AT commands to a modem in Linux?**](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97242/how-to-send-at-commands-to-a-modem-in-linux)

Comment: You could also use [kermit](http://www.kermitproject.org/).

Comment: I am using minicom to establish the serial connection to the board. Once modem started, I use microcom or socat to speak with it. However, It is possible to send AT comands thru this interface by using a simple echo, isn't ?

Comment: Before talk to the modem serial port, you should use the stty or setserial to set the baud rate of the SerialPort.

Answer (score 8):

It is absolutely possible to send AT commands to a modem and capture its output from the command line like you are trying to do, however **not** by just using plain bash shell scripting. Which is why I wrote the program [atinout](http://atinout.sourceforge.net/) specifically to support scenarios like you ask about.

Test like the following:

```
MODEM_DEVICE=/dev/ttyUSB0

MODEM_OUTPUT=`echo AT | atinout - $MODEM_DEVICE -`
case $MODEM_OUTPUT
in
        *OK*)
                echo "Hurray, modem is up and running :)"
                ;;
        *)
                echo "Oh no! Something is not working :("
                ;;
esac
```

If you intend to parse the output in any more sophisticated way you should save the output to a file instead by giving a filename instead of the last `-` and read that.

Comment: To get this working on my Raspberry Pi, I had to switch the source file from using '\r\n' to '\n'. Other than that this works very well!

Comment: Can atinout be used to send SMS for example? I know that it can be used for executing commands without arguments, butt can it be used when we need to type in the message and termination character for sending it?

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to communicate with my Huawei E3372h-158 with @hlovdal's solution, so I rolled my own using `expect` and `screen`, in this case for reading the temperature sensors via `^CHIPTEMP?`:

```
output=$(sudo expect <<EOF
set timeout 5
log_user 0                                                                                                                 spawn sudo screen /dev/ttyUSB0-
sleep 1
send "AT\x5ECHIPTEMP?\r"
expect "OK"
puts "\n-->\$expect_out(buffer)<--"
# Send C-a \ to end the session
send "\x01"
send "\x5C"
EOF
)
# Strip non-printable control characters
output=$(printf "$output" | tr -dc '[:print:]\n' )
printf "$output\n" | grep -P "^\^CHIPTEMP"
```

Hints and caveats: Set `log_user 1` to get the output of `screen`. Not sure `screen` works in all cases as it produces some non-printing characters and perhaps repeating output.